# c# UWP ListView with horizontal ListViews

Tags: c#, listview, scroll, uwp, direction

I have a vertical ListView. It hosts the multiple horizontal ListViews.

Example:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
    </ListView>
    <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
            <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
    </ListView>
</ListView>
```

Now the scroll doesn't work at all, just manipulation with touch.

I need to make scroll with mouse wheel to work only vertically, and manipulation to remain as it is now (both vertical and horizontal).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal ListView, you could edit the default [`ItemsPanelTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemspaneltemplate) and set `Orientation` as `Horizontal` then set `crollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode` to `Enabled`. And you could also the following horizontal `ListView` style directly. I have tested following your code, the style works.

```
<Style x:Key="MyListViewStyle" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                <ContentThemeTransition/>
                <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel 
                    Orientation="Horizontal"  
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                    />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                  BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}" 
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                  HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" 
                                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" 
                                  IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}" 
                                  IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" 
                                  IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" 
                                  IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                  TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}" 
                                  VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" 
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                                  ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}">
                        <ItemsPresenter Footer="{TemplateBinding Footer}" 
                                        FooterTransitions="{TemplateBinding FooterTransitions}"
                                        FooterTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}"
                                        Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                                        HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" 
                                        HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: No, I don't want this effect. I want to have like matrix style. Like this: https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/qigv5dqxbjlh0Q6APFm2Yr5AJS0=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/netflix-home-page-with-account-prompt-5abe9321c064710037911c7a.jpg
Now I am able to move each stripe horizontally with touch, and the whole listview up and down also with touch. I want to make scroll of mouse to work only on main listview, so I can scroll up/down, and to disable it on horizontal stripes. But to leave touch actions as it is.

Comment: If you don't hover mouse on the stripe horizontally the horizontal listview will not been scrolled with mouse wheel.

Comment: But I need to be inside mainlistview, because it will be fullscreen.

Comment: So, currently your main Listview could not be scrolled vertically?

Comment: Currently scroll is not working at all. I need to make it work just vertically.

Comment: Do you mean you just want make main ListView scroll vertically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182773/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-user3239349).